# Наследование классов, работа с классами

Tags: python, классы

Подскажите пожалуйста.Существует два класса: родительский и дочерний. В родительском классе существует 3 экземпляра, которые внесены в список `list_obj`.

Родительский:

```py
class ViewInsur:
    list_obj = []

    def __init__(self, name_view, view, object_insur):
        self.name_view = name_view
        self.view = view
        self.object_insur = object_insur
        self.list_obj.append(self)


one = ViewInsur('Личное', 'жизнь', 'cтрахование жизни')
two = ViewInsur('Имущественное', 'автомобиль', 'Страхование транспортных средств')
three = ViewInsur('Имущественное', 'квартира', 'Страхование жилых объектов')
```

В дочернем классе 1 экземпляр.

Дочерний:

```py
class contract(Branch, ViewInsur):
    def __init__(self, number, date, sum, rate, name, address, phone_number, name_view, view, object_insur):
        super().__init__(name, address, phone_number)
        super().__init__(name_view, view, object_insur)
        self.number = number
        self.date = date
        self.sum = sum
        self.rate = rate
  
  
one_contract = contract(1, '01.01.2019', '1000 руб.', '100 руб.')
two_contract = contract(1, '01.01.2019', '2000 руб.', '100 руб.')
three_contract = contract(1, '01.01.2019', '3000 руб.', '100 руб.')
```

В зависимости от того, какой экземпляр родительского класса я выберу(в main), тот и должен добавиться в экземпляр дочернего класса. Я не совсем понимаю, как это реализовать. То есть на выходе должно быть примерно так:

```
1, '01.01.2019', '1000 руб.', '100 руб.', 'Личное', 'жизнь', 'cтрахование жизни'
```

Большое спасибо за любые советы.

```
def main():
    Branch.show_branch()
    num = int(input())
    print(Branch.list_branch[num])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Откуда берётся родительский класс `Branch`? Можете его предоставить, чтобы код можно было запустить для отладки?

Comment: что такое main, как вы собрались выбирать экземпляр? объясните подробнее что вы хотите..

Comment: Branch еще один класс, он не нужен забыл убрать

Comment: добавила в вопрос